# show items based on user/group or field value

Tags: 2010, list-view

I am not sure what the better approach is for this problem.

we have number of customers that create issues on the system. They will be using Form based authentication approach. Basically, we will have groups of  customers and we will add users to those groups.

but when they login to system, they should not see the issue which were created by other Customer. We already have a Customer field on the issue list which is populated from a top site customer list. but there is no relation between Customer table and User.

So, I need to somehow set the customer field when a customer creates an issue, then filter the list based on this value.

I am sure it is a common requirement on the projects, I was just wondering what the best practice is to achieve this.

Many thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: Have you given any thoughts of adding an EventReceiver to the lists where Issues gets posted, where you break permission inheritance and give users Read permission only on their own items? That way they can only see what they've posted themselves.

Comment: thanks for reply. But it is a kind of ownership concept. seeing their own issues is fine, but I want people to see their colleagues' issues as well..

Comment: That is kind of the same concept. You just do it with a group instead of a user. Same procedure.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have multiple customers in the same group?

Comment: So, do I need to get group of user and break inheritance and give that group read permission for item. is that right? if so, what if the user belongs to more than one group?

Comment: @Lori, we dont have multiple customer in same group, each customer have their own groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your customers are in different groups, then you could easily create a list that shows the Customer name, and the associated group that should be associate with it, then you can write a workflow that will break inheritance and assign permissions to that group by matching the Customer name from the issues list to the customer name in the custom list. This can be done out of the box with SharePoint Designer. Remember to make sure you add a group of users who should be able to see all of the items in the list!